# ng-style apply too late

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this ng-repeat section where i run a directive 'fittext' on p which make sure the text dosent overflow - if it does, fontsize gets decreased. And it works!

However, in IE it doesn't, i noticed from debugging that the style gets added too late. The directive sees nothing is overflowing AND THEN the div size changes which makes it overflow.

```
    <div ng-repeat="data in labelData" ng-style="{'height': chart.labelSize}">

      <div class="labelWrap" style="height: 100%;">

        <p fit-text>
          {{data.label}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can i make sure the ng-style is added before my directive checks for overflow ?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your problem, but maybe ngCloak is what you're looking for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a " missing right after horizontalLabelImageWrap.

Have you tried using [$timeout(fn, 0)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) in your directive?

Maybe it helps:

[Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: the missing " was a typo, sorry. - but ill try to look into timeout, thanks!